# Haskell Indentation Or Mismatched Brackets Error

Tags: haskell

I just started learning haskell and i dont really have too much to say,
this is my code:

```
let issah = "issah"
main = do
    putStrLn(issah)
```

and it shows this error:

```
main.hs:3:1: error:
    parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)
  |
3 | main = do
  | ^
```

Comment: the `let ... makes no sense at outer level.

Comment: Then What do i do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`let` clause isn't allowed at the outer level of Haskell file. It is use, either to define local variables within a function or within a do-block. Notice that in `gchi` you can actually write a top level `let`. Maybe that's where your confusion comes from

```
-- no top level let. Just define the constant issah normaly
issah = "issah"
main = do
    putStrLn(issah)

-- let <local variables> in <expression>
main = let issah = "issah" in putStrLn issah

-- let within do block
main = do
   let issah = "issah"
   putStrLn issah
```

Comment: I would be more explicit in distinguishing a `let` expression from the similar clause allowed in `do` blocks. The fact that they both use the same keyword makes them appear more similar than they really are. (The expression defines the scope in which the bound name is available; the clause implicitly pertains to the rest of the `do` block.)